# Difference Between 'gmake' and 'gmake clean'

Tags: bash, gnu-make

I am currently working on a project on a student job and writing some code. Whenever I want to compile my file, my supervisor told me to first do `gmake clean` and then do `gmake`. Otherwise,some errors from previous gmake may not be solved in the fresh gmake.

My project has a lot of unnecessary files that I am not editing but since i `gmake clean` everytime, the compiler compiles them again everytime which takes a lot of time.

So, if I am not changing the other files, then I don't need to recompile them and the only file that I change is always recompiled simply with `gmake`, right? So why should I `gmake clean` everytime?

Is my supervisor just telling me a *good programming practice* or am I missing some important concept of `gmake clean`?

Comment: It's an issue of what your makefile actually contains.  If you don't have dependencies set up correctly, you will have issues.

Comment: By dependencies, you mean any other file that '#include's the file i am editing? Could you kindly clarify this?

Comment: I think you would get much better responses if you posted an example of a simple makefile that demonstrates what you are actually trying to do.  It doesn't have to be working yet (or you wouldn't be asking), but just to give us an idea of your intentions.

Comment: The GNUMake file is about 1100 lines big. And contains code i don't understand. But this is what it does wheni gmake:

[Debug] Generating dependencies for file1.cpp
[Debug] Generating dependencies for file2.cpp
...
...(similarly for 20 files)
...and
[Debug] Compiling file1.cpp
[Debug] Compiling file2.cpp
...and so on for 20 files.

And it would be great if you could tell me what exactly a dependency is. Thanks.

Comment: Basically all i want to know is that the 10s i spend on compiling the package everytime are worth it or not? gmake takes 1s while a gmake after gmake clean takes over 10s. If its relevant, no new files are created in the process of compiling.
And I am working on a commercial software, I have not created these dependencies etc myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `gmake` and `gmake clean` is that the former builds the default target while the latter "builds" the specific target `clean`, which usually consists of clean-up instructions to remove files that were created during the build process (object files, temporary files, generated code, …). `gmake clean` *should* restore the source tree to a clean state. However, if it actually succeeds depends on how the source tree looks like and what instructions the target contains.

Answer (score 2):

definitely not a best practice... this is usually the quick and dirty solution when the makefile contains a few mistakes and the dependencies are not ok

Answer (score 0):

do `gmake clean` before `gmake` in case you have difficulties to compile. just to check if the problem does not come from an old compiled file.

otherise do only `gmake` in orther to compile your newest changed files.

you superior gived you an advice to handle difficult and strange compilation behavior.